# sum of duration field of max per group in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to create a visualizer by summing up duration field after retrieving max id per group in Elasticsearch. For example:

Data is:

| id | workflow | sid | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | x1 | 1m |
| 1 | A | x2 | 2m |
| 2 | A | x1 | 2m |
| 2 | A | x2 | 3m |
| 1 | B | y1 | 1m |
| 1 | B | y2 | 2m |
| 2 | B | y1 | 2m |
| 2 | B | y2 | 3m |
| 3 | B | y1 | 4m |
| 3 | B | y2 | 2m |

Given the table below, expected returned data as follows, which is max of id per workflow and sum up the duration.

| id | workflow | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 5m |
| 3 | B | 6m |

I'm new to Elasticsearch query and Kibana. Appreciate it if you can provide a pointer how to resolve my problem statement.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my-bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "workflow"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_id": {
          "max": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the search query above with expected bucket of workflow and max id #.  How to use the max id # to retrieve the sid and sum up the duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach that I have learned from Elastic Stack community.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "workflow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "workflow"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id",
            "order": { "max_id": "desc" },
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_id": {
              "max": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            },
            "sum_duration": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "duration"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove `"max_id": { "max": { "field": "id" } }` since this value is already available from the parent agg and accept this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding max_id, it might be easier to sort all buckets by id and only show the top one:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "duration_min": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "sid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "workflow": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}


POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "A", "sid": "x1", "duration_min": 1}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "A", "sid": "x2", "duration_min": 2}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "A", "sid": "x1", "duration_min": 2}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "A", "sid": "x2", "duration_min": 3}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y1", "duration_min": 1}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y2", "duration_min": 2}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y1", "duration_min": 2}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y2", "duration_min": 3}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 3, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y1", "duration_min": 4}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 3, "workflow": "B", "sid": "y2", "duration_min": 2}

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_workflow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "workflow"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sids": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sid"
              }
            },
            "duration_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "duration_min"
              }
            },
            "sales_bucket_sort": {
              "bucket_sort": {
                "sort": [
                  { "_key": { "order": "desc" } } 
                ],
                "size": 1                              
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, it helps my understanding.

Comment: Heh. Not sure what I was thinking here. Yeah, your solution is much better. :)